Identifying a PIR device
I have a PIR (passive Infrared sensor that has an unmarked IC in it that performs all the PIR related functions. The only other active component on the module is  voltage regulator. I would like to identify the PIR IC.
Can anyone advise what the all-in-one PIR device is or may be?
Unlike most (all?) PIR units that I have seen so far this one uses no ICs external to the "photodiode can". It has no adjustment of parameters such as attack and hold time - which is the same functionality as found on other basic lower cost units.
The units work well and I do not need the adjustments, which cam be managed in software, but I'm disinclined to use these even in prototype units without knowing the core device or direct functional equivalent. Also, knowing the IC or an equivalent would allow me to seek a more formal source. This is a shame as they are compact, low cost, work well and have a suitably low quiescent current of about 50 microamps.


Murata make a nice IR sensor that may be similar: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3968251.pdf. I'm not sure what IC you are referring to. In your sketch you appear to show a voltage regulator <-- is this the item you refer to? I'm confused because in your opening line you want to identify an IC and then go on to show a device that you say has no external IC. Do you see the reason for my confusion Russ?

Better data sheet for same part: https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/infrared/ira/ira-s410st01-e.ashx?la=en

@Andyaka  Thanks. My 2nd one-line paragraph described what I wanted BUT I see that the first paragraph was indeed somewhat ambiguous. My brain filtered out the voltage regulator as I was focused on the PIR device :-). I've edited it. The VR happens to be a gem - when you reduce Vin to Vout it has a differential voltage of under 10 mV - admittedly at about 50 uA. || After asking the question I had another look around and all sorts of devices sprung into view. I don't know what happened originally as I'm usually reasonably good at web searching.

You can find devices like this from Asian distributors such as lcsc.
For example, this inexpensive Huizhou Newopto part:


There are other manufacturers and different options, including TO-5 packages with more pins that allow timing adjustment and so on. Basically they've put the entire circuit of a PIR security light inside a TO-5 package, save the power supply and power switching components! And it runs from a whiff of current (microamperes).

Must have had brain fade. Soon after asking I found many. Yours has a very low quiescent current, which is very welcome as I an in one application running an LED at 150 uA for lighting (!!!) . It's amazing how useful about 30 milli-lumen can be. If a PIR used 50 uA then it pays to make the LED PIR operated but the gain in energy is not marvellous. Their claimed 10 uA is most welcome. It is a very undemanding application compared to many - Is there someone in the toilet cubicle?
.

These days you can get thermopile detectors too, so you can detect something warm as opposed to something warm and moving. Depending on what you're after. If someone sits on the throne for a while without moving much the PIR detector can throw a vacant status.
